# How to get the 'id' for accessing user details in instagram

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instagram

How do i get the `id` for accessing user info by `(Hashie::Mash)user(id)` method of the instagram API or accessing his/her location by  `(Hashie::Mash)location(id)`?

I am using rails for my project.

Comment: Could you add some more information on how you are accessing the Instagram API and maybe post the code in question?
Are you using ActiveResource?

Comment: I have installed the instagram gem. In the yard doc -> [ rubydoc.info/github/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/master/Instagram/Client/Locations#location_recent_media-instance_method ] it is given that Instagram.location(id) gives info about a given instagram location. How do i obtain this 'id' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for a user to get his/her id, e.g:

```
shaynesids = Instagram.user_search("Shayne Sweeney")
```

That will give you all the ids on an array of user matching Shayne Sweeny (hopefully just one), then you can use it with user(id), like this:

```
myuser = Instagram.user(shaynesids.first)
```

Note: In here I'm assuming that the search it's gonna return at least one result, you will need to be careful in your code to account for errors, because it could return an empty array.