# How to get 'id' parameter from the instagram api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instagram

Can someone tell me "how to get" or "what is" the 'id' parameter that is used in the ruby instagram api methods `location(id), location_recent_media(id,options{}), media_item(id), media_likes(id)` etc given in the yard documentation http://rubydoc.info/github/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem ? I am using rails and the api is installed using gem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the 'id' for accessing user details in instagram](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800459/how-to-get-the-id-for-accessing-user-details-in-instagram)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see an example of how to use the API in here https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem, taking a look at the code I would say that the id is dependent on what you are querying, if you are using location(id) it would be the id of the location. Now, to get from a "real world" location to that id I believe you can use location_search(longitude, latitude) and that would give you an array with all the locations close to that coordinates, e.g (from the code documentation):

```
Instagram.location_search("37.7808851", "-122.3948632")
```

That would give you an array with the locations around 37.7808851, -122.3948632 (164 S Park, SF, CA USA).

Then you can use that array of ids with location(id), e.g:

```
mylocations = Instagram.location_search("37.7808851", "-122.3948632")
Instagram.location(mylocations.first)
```

Hope it helps.